# C# EntityFramework: Update / Add / Delete arbitrarily complex entity graph

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to develop application using REACT.JS on frontend and C# EntityFramework based REST API on backend.

Suppose I have entity relationships like this:

```
Form ONE-TO-MANY Element
Element ONE-TO_MANY Attribute
```

What I am trying to do is a simple controller, that could simply add/update/delete such Form with all related entities.

I have created an application in REACT with following structure:

```
<SyncComponent>
    <FormComponent>
        <ElementsList>
            <ElementComponent>
                <AttributesList>
                    <AttributeComponent>
```

`<SyncComponent>`, that is meant to perform AJAX request to resver, will obtain full JSON representation of the Form, that might look like this:

- New `Form` Created:

  ```
  {"name":"MyNewForm", "elements":[{"name":"MyNewElement","attributes":[{"name":"MyNewAttribute","value":"MyValue"}]}]}
  ```
- New `Element` added to existing `Form`:

  ```
  {"id": 1, "name":"MyExistingForm", "elements":[{"name":"MyNewElement","attributes":[{"name":"MyNewAttribute","value":"MyValue"}]}]}
  ```
- Updated attribute in existing `Element` and added new `Element` to `Form`:

  ```
  {  
      "id":123,
      "name":"MyExistingForm",
      "elements":[  
          {  
              "id":321
              "name":"MyExistingElement",
              "attributes":[  
                  {
                      "id":456 
                      "name":"MyExisitngAttribute",
                      "value":"MyUpdatedValue"
                  },
                  {
                      "name":"MyNewAttribute",
                      "value":"MyNewValue"
                  }
              ]
          },
          {  
              "name":"MyNewElement",
              "attributes":[  
                  {  
                      "name":"MyNewAttribute",
                      "value":"MyNewValue"
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
  }
  ```

... so basically an tree with arbitrary distibuted CREATE and UPDATE tasks (DELETE tasks will invoke, if elemnt is missing in JSON, but its present in database/object representation constructed form database). I know that I need to send whole big object only when a small change occured, but I find still much better than sending a separate request on each entity change. Firstly, I see my approach way simpler to implement on client side, secondly, I will end up with one request instead of dozen and finally, application is meant to allow user to make multiple changes Form and when done, hit "Save" button to update state. This way, I couldn't end up in inconsistent state, eg. when some of the AJAX for certain requests will fail, some not etc.

To sync this JSON on server side, I have auto-generated MVC API Controller.

**The problem I am stucked on is that EntityFramework could not properly parse given JSON to graph of objects to arbitrary depth.** It works good to depth 1, but not deeper.

Explanation by example: 
when invking `PutForm()` function (look at code below), `form` attribute oviously contains instance of `Form`, `form.elements` contains collection of passed `Element`'s, but `form.elements.toList[0].attributes` is always empty, even if in JSON there are some `attribute`s passed.

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    public class FormController : ApiController
    {
        private FormAsAServiceDbContext db = new FormAsAServiceDbContext();

        // ...

        // PUT: api/Form/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutForm(int id, Form form)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != form.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(form).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!FormExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

How do I enforce EntityFramework to construct full objects graph properly from JSON, co I could perform atomic update/creation/removal of this arbitrarily complex graph of entities?

Comment: first, graph is an unusual term, and you're using it when describing conceptually different things: i.e. object, model, or type. second, entities are models that are initiated (the instance of) by the ef context; with the exception being the case of insertion. `db.Entry(form)` needs to be attached (Added State) before it can be modified. You need to satisfy any foreign key constraints in that operation.

Comment: what is `FormAsAServiceDbContext`, it seems like a completely leaky abstraction.

Comment: oh.. nevermind, I see you're attempting to modify an existing Form.. still, you should be querying the context for the form instance, and **putting** the elements into the entities collection..  at any rate, your issue is purely ajax posting and mvc framework serialization here. The JSON you referenced, you've verified that is what is being posted from web developer tools?

Comment: the most relevant information you've provided on your issue is "form.elements.toList[0].attributes is always empty, even if ... attributes passed" ... It is generally a serialization setting determining 'depth' or recursion. Still, I'm not sure that modifying the state of `Form` type instances will necessarily propagate or reflect state changes of `DbSet<AttributeComponent>` (presuming that's the repository and Entity Type name) even the attributes were serialized..

Comment: the default level of 'depth' in MVC is 100, so that's unlikely the issue.. unless you've set it to 1 somewhere.. update your question, and include the actual .NET classes/model/entities.. in particular `Form` and `Attribute`.. also, feel free to remove out-of-context information like the REACT markup, and just provide 1 JSON snippet.. there's a bit TMI in that regard... EF also seems a bit out-of-context to your issue as well, but your methodology and implementation could very well provide concerning results even after addressing the serialization issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@Brett Caswell** you are completely right with

> the most relevant information you've provided on your issue is
>   "form.elements.toList[0].attributes is always empty, even if ...
>   attributes passed"

Long description, simple problem. Name of collection `attributes` does not corresponded exactly to property in model object, so once I have changed it, mapping started to works (to any depth), so now I just need to iterate over them and set state to *Added* or *Modified*, depending on whether ID is 0 or not.